# Is there any console command that grants invincibility on a target?

Tags: dota-2, cheats

I want to practice a combo skill on a hero. Is there any cheat that makes the target immortal? I just want to be able to cast my skills on him, then refresh; over and over until I can do it properly.

Comment: Isn't there a way to create a custom game with bots and you being the sole human? I know it's possible with LoL and if possible with Dota 2, would give you plenty of time to practice.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, but I think the problem here is that the bots eventually die.  I think melvnberd wants an immortal enemy to practice on.

Comment: @JohntheGreen There's still plenty of minions coming out, waves after waves, giving him lot of targets to practice on. I understand what he wants but I'm pretty sure the best solution is a custom game. I don't see how, without having your own server to change the settings, you'll get a immortal target.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, there are targets, but moving ones that tend to die on their own.  His is actually a fairly common request, and there is a commonly used workaround.  You aren't wrong, though: the best solution *is* a custom game. One with cheats that lets him spawn in enemy heroes to practice on.

Comment: I must say the new title is a lot better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It would appear not.](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Cheats?cookieSetup=true)

What I see most people do is spawn in an enemy Centaur Warrunner and give him 6 Hearts of Tarrasque, which should let you practice your combo a few times at least, and give him tons of regen.

In theory, that should be possible with this:

```
-createhero centaur
-givebots item_heart
-givebots item_heart
-givebots item_heart
-givebots item_heart
-givebots item_heart
-givebots item_heart
```

Optionally you can throw in `-lvlbots 25` to level your centaur up to 25 for that awesome strength gain.

---

<sup>You may or may not have to add `enemy` after `centaur`, depending on which side you are.  It seems to be tied directly to radiant/dire rather than which side is actually your enemy.</sup>

Comment: I see its impossible to have a non-moving target though.. but thank you @john the Green for giving me an alternative to work on..

Comment: @melvnberd The enemy centaur this should create for you to practice with should be very much non-moving.

Answer (score 2):

You can spawn an Abbadon and use the wtf mode. This means his ultimate does not have a cooldown, which makes him nearly invincible. Except if you deal over 400 damage in one instance you are able to nuke him down to zero without activating his ult.

But this have a downside: his ultimate removes any negative buff. If you need a specific negative buff (ethereral blade, orchid, hex) for your combo, you have to stay with the tanky centaur.

Comment: Clever solution, though bear in mind this means you'd have wtf mode on your hero too, which I don't think should usually matter, but it might :)